# Maven "process-classes" phase called for each reporting plugin (multiple executions)

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have a Maven artefact that includes data computed at compile-time

This is achieved by using the `exec-maven-plugin` to call the generating class.

This is correctly being executed when the artefact is built, but when reporting plugins are added, the execution is happening multiple times, slowing it down significantly.

Take the following `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <main.class>test.Runner</main.class>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <id>${main.class}</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.9.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

When `clean install site` is run, the test.Runner is called three time - and each time a reporting plugin is added, it's run again.

Comment: Why have you define the maven-surefire-report-plugin twice? Doesn't that produce a warning? Apart from that can you explain more in detail what exactly you problem is?

Comment: @khmarbaise it was to illustrate the problem, each time a reporting plugin is added, even a duplicate, will cause the exec plugin to re-run.
My problem is that I only want to run the exec once, but right now it’s happening multiple times, and the extra times seem solely caused by the reporting plugins.

Comment: So what happens if you just use `mvn clean install`?

Comment: @khmarbaise it runs once - but the site isn’t produced, and none of the reports are created.

Comment: You might try to use `mvn clean install site:site` ...also the question is are you aware of using a report plugin which forkes the life cycle like https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html `Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase test prior to executing itself.` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise ``site:site`` has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the reports config to this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
  <reportSets>
    <reportSet>
      <reports>
        <report>report-only</report>
      </reports>
    </reportSet>
  </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

This tells Maven which reports should be run. Without that `reportSet` config,

> every reporting goal available in the plugin is rendered once

per the [Maven Site plugin docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/configuring-reports.html). This is important because as @khmarbaise notes, the [report mojo](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html)

> Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase test prior to executing itself.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense :)